# Second order homogeneous differential equations with constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose we wish to solve the second-order homogeneous differential
>   equation ay″ + by′ + cy = 0, (3)
>
> where a, b, and c are constants. To solve Equation (3), we seek a
>   function which when multiplied by a constant and added to a constant
>   times its first derivative plus a constant times its second derivative
>   sums identically to zero.
>
> ```
> One function that behaves this way is the
> exponential function 
>
>     y = e^rx
> ```
>
> , when r is a constant.

This is how my textbook proceeds to solve the equation (3) and it works, but is  y = e^rx the only function that can solve (3) ? Then why does everybody use y=e^rx ?

Answer (score 1):

For $a=1,b=0,c=1$, the solution of the ODE is $C_1\cos x+ C_2 \sin x$. So $e^{rx}$ is not the only kind of solution.

Comment: no, we want a function like y = e^rx, that can be plugged into (3), which reduces (3) into its auxillary form

Comment: No it is not, that is used to check the roots of the characteristic equation. If they are distinct and real then it would be of the form $e^{r_1x}$ and $e^{r_2x}$, otherwise you have to choose different basis functions(Like I showed in my answer). One can show that if the wronskian of the basis function is nonzero, then the solution is unique. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian. For the case of distinct and real roots of characteristic equation with constant coefficients, the solution is always unique.

Comment: But my textbook seems too use the same basis function for non-real roots and non-distinct roots